# Hello, need help on jTable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable

i have a problem here of displaying a date type from ms access db to jtable... i can't seem get it to work, and try to modified my codes but still didn't lucky, i hope someone here could offer me another idea...

here is my sample code to populate my jtable with data from database:

```
public void PopulatejTable(){
    DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(35);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
    jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);

    String dbuser = "";
    String dbpasswd = "";
    String DriverPrefix = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\\myWork2\\PersonalInfo\\db1.mdb";

    String SQLString = ("select ID,Username,Password,Website from Table1 order by ID");

    try{
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+e.getMessage(),"JDBC DRIVER Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rset = null;

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(DriverPrefix,dbuser,dbpasswd);
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(SQLString);
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+e.getMessage(),"Connection Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
    while(model.getRowCount()>0){
        model.removeRow(0);
    }

    try{
        rset = stmt.executeQuery();
        while(rset.next()){
            int ID = rset.getInt(1);
            String Username = rset.getString(2);
            String Password = rset.getString(3);
            String Website = rset.getString(4);
            Date DateEncoded = rset.getDate(5);
            model.addRow(new Object[]{ID,Username,Password,Website,DateEncoded});
        }
        rset.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    }catch(SQLException e){
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage(),"Communication Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

and this is the errors i get:

```
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)
    at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
    at UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm.PopulatejTable(MainForm.java:1302)
    at UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm.<init>(MainForm.java:71)
    at UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm$29.run(MainForm.java:1398)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

thanks to someone who could help me... :) :) :)

Comment: are you getting any error? if so, post it here..

Comment: am not sure, does it have line number 1302 in your above piece of code? since, its hitting the exception at "UsernamePasswordPackage.MainForm.PopulatejTable(MainForm.java:1302)"... check it out..

Comment: i get a new error that says [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Drivers]Invalid descriptor index. thank you guys, you helped me a lot to my project... many many thanks :) :) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by looking at your error codes it looks like you don't have enough columns.

```
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(100);


Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 >= 4 at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427) at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
```

Comment: thank you sir, i added a new column for my date type. but it gives me another error that says [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Drivers]Invalid descriptor index. do i need to format my column for date formatted type? thank you again sir...

Comment: I'm not sure, never worked with Microsoft Access. My recommendation is to google it.